# Php exec with Java

Tags: java, php, exec, javac

I have a working exec("java $file") command in php, but the problem is that I'm not sure how to get standard output from a java program.

I realize that there is a second parameter (for example, exec("java $file", $output) ) but that doesn't seem to return output from a java program.

For example, if I have a java program with just a println("Hello World") in it, how can I get that output through exec() in php?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
string exec ( string $command [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```

> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command

Example:

```
exec('java ' . $file, $output);
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

nevermind. Okay, it works. You must run a print_r on the output to print the array, then you will see standard output.

Comment: print_r is just a print statement that works with arrays and objects as well as strings. It doesn't do anything to $output, it was always working.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be using `popen()` or the even more general [`proc_open()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)